# Given that the sum of five positive real numbers is 100. Prove that there are two numbers among them whose difference is at most 10 using PHP.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I did this:

Assume all numbers have a difference that is bigger than $10$. Let these $5$ numbers be $a>b>c>d>e>0$. So we have $$a>b+10>c+20>d+30>e+40>40$$So, $$a>e+40, \quad b>e+30, \quad c>e+20, \quad d>e+10$$ So $$100=a+b+c+d+e>5e+100>100$$ Contradiction.

But is there a way that we can use to solve this exact same problem using pigeonhole principle (PHP) ?

Comment: I'd have said your argument was optimal.

Comment: Yeah I know that this argument is perfectly fine, but I'm adamant in trying to do this using PHP.

Comment: If the distance between numbers need to be at least 10, then starting from 0, numbers can at best be placed in intervals of 10.

Comment: I think the argument is that the earliest pigeon must be at least in pigeonhole $1$,  the next pigeon must then be at least eleven higher so at least in hole $12$,  the next at least in  $23$, the next at least in  $34$,    and the last at least    in pigeonhole $45$, so the labels of the pigeonholes must add up to at least $115$.  It is your argument plus the word *pigeonhole*

Comment: Your argument is using the pigeonhole principle, sort of.  The "minimal placement" still has one in $(0,10]$, one in $(10,20]$, etc.  Really, this is just your argument.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot solve the entire problem using PHP alone. Here is a method which uses PHP as a step.

We prove by induction on $n$ that if there are $n$ positive real numbers whose sum is at most $5n(n-1)$, then there will exist two whose  difference is at most $10$. The base case $n=2$ should be obvious.

For the inductive step, there are two cases. Suppose that one of the real numbers is greater than $10(n-1)$. It follows that the sum of the remaining $n-1$ real numbers is at most
$$
5n(n-1)-10(n-1)=5(n-1)(n-2)
$$
Therefore, we can apply the induction hypothesis to these remaining $n-1$ numbers to conclude that there exist two of them whose difference is at most $10$.

In the other case, all of the real numbers must be in the range $[0,10(n-1))$. This interval can be partitioned into $n-1$ intervals of length $10$. These intervals are the holes, and the $n$ numbers are the pigeons. By PHP, there are two numbers in the same interval. Clearly, their distance must be at most $10$.